# Jquery append with Laravel: Cannot end a section without first starting one

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to dynamically populate data in a section of my blade file using Ajax. Code goes like this:

```
@if(count($chat) != 0)
  @foreach($chat as $d)

    <a href="#" class="media border-bottom-blue-grey border-bottom-lighten-5" id="link{{ $d->id }}">
    
     <div class="media-body w-100">
     <h6 class="list-group-item-heading font-medium-1 text-bold-700">{{ $d->name }}{{ $d->unread_messages }}
     @if( $d->unread_messages > 0)
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger lighten-3">{{ $d->unread_messages }}</span></span> 
    </h6>
    @endif
    </div>

    </a>

    <div id="target"></div>

    <script>

     var link_id ="#link";
     $(link_id.concat( {{ $d->id }} )).click(function(e) { // Bind closure to #link1's onClick event
       e.preventDefault();
       jQuery.get('show/{{ $d->id }}', function(data) { // Perform AJAX GET request
        var html = "<h1> Hello </h1>"
        $('target').@append(html); 
         });
       });

     </script>

  @endforeach
@endif
```

Basically, am rendering chatboxes populated with data ($chat) from the Controller. When the boxes are clicked, am calling a route ('show/{{ $d->id }}') with data to populate the empty #target div (that logic is not complete yet so currently am trying to append the simpler html variable).

However, whenever I load this page, I get the following error: **Cannot end a section without first starting one**

NOTE: When I remove the following line of code, the page loads without any problem.

```
    $('target').@append(html);
```

Is there something am missing here, how can I improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this line, I suppose that there is a syntax error with your append line:

```
    $('#target').append(html);
```

Edit: Ok I was checking your code so, here I'm going to add my suggestion:

```php
@if(count($chat) != 0)
  @foreach($chat as $d)

    <a href="#" class="media border-bottom-blue-grey border-bottom-lighten-5" id="link{{ $d->id }}">
    
         <div class="media-body w-100">
             <h6 class="list-group-item-heading font-medium-1 text-bold-700">{{ $d->name }}{{ $d->unread_messages }}
                 @if( $d->unread_messages > 0)
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger lighten-3">{{ $d->unread_messages }}</span>
                @endif
            </h6>
        </div>

    </a>

    <div id="target{{ $d->id }}"></div>

    <script>

     $("#link{{ $d->id }}" ).on('click', function(e) { // Bind closure to #link1's onClick event
         e.preventDefault();
         jQuery.get('show/{{ $d->id }}', function(data) { // Perform AJAX GET request
             var html = "<h1> Hello </h1>"
             $('target').append(html); 
         });
     });

     </script>

  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Tried it, didnt work. Actually whatever id I use in there doesnt seem to make a difference. I think the issue is with the flow of the blade code.

Comment: thanks David, I had overlooked the .append syntax, focused on the id naming

Comment: Thank you @lagbox. I fix that the first time and the forgot remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The `@append(...)` part is being interpretted as a Blade directive, the `@append` directive:

```
$('target').@append(html);
```

Remove the `@` from that:

```
$('target').append(html);
```

The `appendSection` method:

```
public function appendSection()
{
    if (empty($this->sectionStack)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Cannot end a section without first starting one.');
    }
```

Comment: gee whiz, could it be that simple?

Comment: yes, its the same thing the other answer is saying

Comment: oh I see, i had concentrated on the id name part, overlooked the rest

Comment: this just adds the explanation of why there is an error